# i want to add value from b table to a and subtract values from c to a

Tags: php

I am developing inventory page in php with database as mentioned below. I have some complex equation which I am unable to resolve. Please help me out.

I have one table name "A" with column X and Y having values as follows:

Table "A"

```
------------
X        Y
------------
blue     0
yellow   0
brown    0
```

Table "B" in following pattern.

```
------------
X        Y
------------
blue    50
yellow  15
blue    20
brown    5
```

similarly Table "C"

```
------------
X        Y
------------
blue    15
yellow  10
blue     5
brown    5
```

Now what I want if I add record in table "B" as mention above it should be updated in table "A" with following equation.

`"A"= "B"-"C"`

result should be i.e

Table "A"

```
------------
X        Y
------------
blue    20
yellow   5
brown    0
```

same in case of adding in records table "C" equation should be as follows:

please note X values in table "A" are DISTINCT where as in other table are not.

Comment: What formula did you use to arrive at A blue=20 at the end? B has 50+20 blue, and C has 15+5. Shouldn't A=B-C be 70-20=50?

Comment: 70 is sum of blue from x column (table B) and 20 is sum of blue from X column (table C).

Comment: Right, so A blue should be 50, according to your formula.

Comment: yea its been erroneously written 20; apologies for that.....

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();

// Sum all from B
foreach ($db->query('SELECT * FROM B')->fetchAll() as $row)
{
    $results[$row['X']] += $row['Y'];
}

// Substract all from C
foreach ($db->query('SELECT * FROM C')->fetchAll() as $row)
{
    $results[$row['X']] -= $row['Y'];
}

// Insert result into A
foreach ($results as $X => $Y)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO A (X, Y) VALUES ('$X', '$Y')");
}
```

This assumes that you have created a PDO object named `$db`. Tweak it if you're using a different database extension.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use `AFTER INSERT` triggers on tables `B` and `C`

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_b_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE a 
     SET y = 
  (
    SELECT 
    (
      SELECT SUM(y) 
        FROM B
       WHERE x = NEW.x
    ) -
    (
      SELECT SUM(y) 
        FROM C
       WHERE x = NEW.x
    )
  )
   WHERE x = NEW.x;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_c_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON c
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE a 
     SET y = 
  (
    SELECT 
    (
      SELECT SUM(y) 
        FROM B
       WHERE x = NEW.x
    ) -
    (
      SELECT SUM(y) 
        FROM C
       WHERE x = NEW.x
    )
  )
   WHERE x = NEW.x;
```

Then you just insert new rows into `B` and `C`

```sql
INSERT INTO B VALUES ('blue', 5);
INSERT INTO C VALUES ('blue', 10);
```

and triggers maintain `Y` value in table `A`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d12cc/1)** demo

Comment: @user2649714 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?